# C# regular expression not to match certain words in string

Tags: c#, regex, regex-lookarounds

I have been trying for hours to work out a solution for this problem. Let say there is a string

```
"hello Exclude1 4:32  test test Exclude2 5:23 hello 2:19 some more text 42:3 more text"
```

I am trying to create a C# regx which will only match `2:19` and `42:3` 
but ignore `Exclude1 4:32` and `Exclude2 5:23`

i.e don't match  4:32 or n:nn if it is preceded by Exclude1 or Exclude2.
Thanks

Comment: You need to give a _rule_ for what should and shouldn't be matched.

Comment: Are you looking for all \d+:\d+ not preceded by Exclude\d+  ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a [**negative lookbehind**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookbehind) to ignore an expression preceeded by some other expression:

```
(?<!Exclude1 )(?<!Exclude2 )\d+:\d+
```

This will match `##:##` that is not immediately preceeded by either `Exclude1`  or `Exclude2` .

Demos: [**Regular Expression**](http://www.rubular.com/r/yCfI8MUvSA) | [**C# Code Sample**](http://ideone.com/JPfREU)

Comment: @Rohit I was stuck at string pattern = @"(?<!Exclude1)[\d]{1,3}:[\d]{1,3}"

Comment: Thanks @mellamokb for your out of the box solution

Comment: @mellamokb plz have a look http://www.rubular.com/r/p8KpwxvJC8. This matches 4:3 from Exclude2 54:3. Though I changed regex to (?<!Exclude1)(?<!Exclude2)\s\d+:\d+ and it works fine but not sure if my tweak is the best way to do it

Comment: Good catch. Your solutions is probably the simplest, if there is always exactly one space between the `Exclude` expression and the start of the digits.

Answer (score 0):

```
 (?<!a)b for example matches b which is not preceded by a, you can
 easily adapt it to your needs.
```

Comment: Thanks Kode Slacker for explaining the concept

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like :

`(?<!Exclude\d )\d+:\d+`

Comment: Thanks willOEM for the solution. This does fits nicely as a solution for my question I posted and an addition to my knowledge. however Exclude1 or Exclude2 I used to make question simple actually they are from a set of different words which I was trying to exclude.